# vue-socket.io How to connect to multiple websocket servers

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I try to connect to two different web-socket Servers from a VUE-Client with [vue-socket.io](https://github.com/MetinSeylan/Vue-Socket.io) like this:

```
import { store } from '@/store/store'
import { store2 } from '@/store/store2'

Vue.use(Vuex)

Vue.use(VueSocketio, 'http://192.168.1.101:8000', store)
Vue.use(VueSocketio, 'http://192.168.1.102:8001', store2)
```

I have created 2 store files `store.js` and `store2.js`

Actually the first `Vue.use(VueSocketio…` line will connect and work properly, but the second will not. So in the upper example `Port 8000` connects but not `Port 8001`. When I swap the two lines `Port 8001` will connect but `Port 8000` will not.

All Examples I found deal only with one Web-socket Server and that works fine.
What is the best practice to connect to multiple Web-socket Servers with a VUE-Client?

Any idea how I get both connected?

Comment: Use socket.io-client package instead because Vue Socket IO dont support multiple websocket server!

Answer (score 2):

You can find the solution on Github:
https://github.com/MetinSeylan/Vue-Socket.io/pull/98

### Adding multiple namespaces/socket connetions

```js
let connectObj = {
  notification: 'http://localhost:5000/notification',
  client: 'http://localhost:5000/client'
}
Vue.use(VueSocketio, connectObj, store)
```

This adds capability to listen to multiple socket instances (for ex- namespaces) in single Vue instance.
If connection is passed as an object, the keys can be used to identify and thus will be able to isolate listeners.