# How to connect multiple sockets in a single vuejs project?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, websocket, vuex, vue-socket.io

```
import VueSocketIOExt from 'vue-socket.io-extended';
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';

const socket = io('http://localhost:3200/');
const socket1 = io('http://localhost:3100/');

Vue.use(VueSocketIOExt, socket);
Vue.use(VueSocketIOExt, socket1);
```

I tried using the above code. But only only socket is working. Is it possible to connect both the sockets simultaneously.

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51726558/vue-socket-io-how-to-connect-to-multiple-websocket-servers

Comment: have you tried adding the *forceNew* flag on the options, for example: `io("<addr>", { forceNew: true })`

Comment: yes. I did and it didnt worked

Comment: I need to connect multiple sockets at the same time. In this case when I am calling socket() socket ID of only the first socket is receiving.

Answer (score -1):

`Vue.use(VueSocketIOExt, socket1)` is probably overriding `Vue.use(VueSocketIOExt, socket)`, hence only the last one is taking into account IMO.

What if you try the following?

```js
Vue.use(VueSocketIOExt, socket)
Vue.use(VueSocketIOExt2, socket1)
```

Comment: I need to connect multiple sockets at the same time. In this case when I am calling socket() socket ID of only the first socket is receiving.